# Adding additional HTML attrs using HiddenInput

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use Django forms to create HTML forms inputs with type="hidden" and also a custom id and class.
Desired result:

```
<input type="hidden" name="techniciansignature" id="techniciansignature" name="techniciansignature" maxlength="255" />
```

django.form.widget Django source

```
class HiddenInput(Input):
    input_type = 'hidden'
    is_hidden = True

class TextInput(Input):
    input_type = 'text'
```

forms.py

```
sign1 = {
         'id':'estimate_sign_date'
         }

sign2 = {
         'id':'techniciansignature'
         }

sign3 = {
         'id':'approversignature'
         }

estimate_sign_date = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=TextInput(attrs=sign1), max_length=255)
techniciansignature = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=HiddenInput(attrs=sign2), max_length=255)
approversignature = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=HiddenInput(attrs=sign3), max_length=255)
```

Source viewed in Chrome:

```
<input type="text" id="estimate_sign_date" name="estimate_sign_date" maxlength="255" />
<input type="hidden" name="techniciansignature" />
<input type="hidden" name="approversignature" />
```

Why are attributes not included in the HiddenInput widget but work fine for TextInput?

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
techniciansignature = forms.CharField(required=False,
                                      widget=HiddenInput(attrs=sign2),
                                      max_length=255,
                                      initial='YOUR TEXT')
```

Comment: The issue was using {{ form.techniciansignature.as_hidden }} in the template was overriding the widget.

Comment: You should be render the form of this way {{ form }} or {{ form.as_p }}, {{ form.as_table }} {{ form.as_ul }}. If you want that the form render of other way, you must to create a method. {{ form.my_render_form }}. You can se here a example http://tracpub.yaco.es/djangoapps/browser/formadmin/trunk/formadmin/forms.py#L34

Answer (score 0):

If i render this form:

```
class F(forms.Form):
    estimate_sign_date = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=TextInput(attrs=sign1), max_length=255)
    techniciansignature = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=HiddenInput(attrs=sign2), max_length=255)
```

The result is (on Django (1, 3, 1, 'final', 0):

```
<label for="estimate_sign_date">Estimate sign date:</label> 
<input type="text" id="estimate_sign_date" name="estimate_sign_date" maxlength="255" />
<input type="hidden" id="techniciansignature" name="techniciansignature" />
```

Comment: The issue was using {{ form.techniciansignature.as_hidden }} in the template was overriding the widget. What should I do once I have figured this out to make this post more useful?

Comment: Add your answer to the question